# How to compute this determinant connected to Kac matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

compute
\begin{vmatrix}
 \lambda  & 1 &  &  &  & \\
 n & \lambda  & 2 &  &  & \\
  & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots  &  & \\
  &  & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots  & \\
  &  &  & 2 & \lambda & n \\
  &  &  &  & 1 & \lambda 
\end{vmatrix}

I tried to find some recurrence relations, but I failed. I added all the rows except the first row to the first row, but I can't find any useful equations. How to compute it?

Comment: It is unclear what the pattern of the subdiagonal element is, could there be a typo?

Comment: Oh you're right. There is a typo.

Comment: You say you've tried some recurrence relations. Can we see what exactly you've tried, and how you derive these recurrence relations?

Comment: please, show the first values, for $n=1,2,3,4$

Comment: Emmm...if the subdiagonal elements are the same, I can find some recurrence relations to get the result, since I've computed some example. Unfortunately, the subdiagonal elements are not equal, and i think that's the difficulty with calculating it. Now i might already know the answer after computing the determinant when n=3, 4, 5, 6, but I still want a general solution.